# Rendering database UTC timestamp as local with Telerik controls

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

We're using the Telerik (PHP UI) controls but there appears to be something that I'm not able to crack.

We store timestamps in the backend database in UTC, and when using a Grid to display such items, I want to be able to show that UTC timestamp converted into the local users timezone (the TZ data is stored as a PHP variable, different people logging in could be in different TZs). It appears I'm not the only one that's asking this, as the Telerik forum someone else asks the same question but without an answer (scroll to the bottom of that [forum post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/utc-to-local-datetime-in-grid)).

From the Telerik [site](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/dateparsing#parse-utc-date-strings) I it appears that all I'd have to do is to format the date with a format with "zzz" appended to the date, but all this does is add the offset to the displayed time (eg `2020-02-27 10:00:00` -> `2020-02-27 10:00:00-0800`) ... but it does do this "auto-magically" which I suppose is nice ... (heavy sarcasm)

This [forum post](https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides) also shows that an onRequestEnd call should do what I need it to do, but when I attempt this, nothing appears to change.

Can anyone offer up any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Note : I've created the outer table with the following:

```
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');
```

**Solution:** I achieved this by adding the following to the page:

```
function dataSource_requestEnd(e){
    var data = e.sender.options.data.data;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var td = data[i];
        for (var key in td){
            if (key === "NameOfDateField"){
                var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
                new Date(td[key].setMinutes(td[key].getMinutes() - offset));
            }
        }
    }
 }


$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    dataSource.bind("requestEnd", dataSource_requestEnd);
    dataSource.fetch();
});
```

Please note that **NameOfDateField** was the name of the key in the array that was returned from the dataSource.

TBH, I'm not at all sure how the data got converted, but certainly the **offset** and **localTime** variables are vital to this succeeding (although to my mind, they don't actually update anything?!)